# How do I converted my textfile to a nested json in python

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, logging

I have a text file which I want to convert to a nested json structure. The text file is :

```
Report_for Reconciliation
Execution_of application_1673496470638_0001
Spark_version 2.4.7-amzn-0
Java_version 1.8.0_352 (Amazon.com Inc.)
Start_time 2023-01-12 09:45:13.360000
Spark Properties: 
Job_ID 0
Submission_time 2023-01-12 09:47:20.148000
Run_time 73957ms
Result JobSucceeded
Number_of_stages 1
Stage_ID 0
Number_of_tasks 16907
Number_of_executed_tasks 16907
Completion_time 73207ms
Stage_executed parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53
Job_ID 1
Submission_time 2023-01-12 09:48:34.177000
Run_time 11525ms
Result JobSucceeded
Number_of_stages 2
Stage_ID 1
Number_of_tasks 16907
Number_of_executed_tasks 0
Completion_time 0ms
Stage_executed parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53
Stage_ID 2
Number_of_tasks 300
Number_of_executed_tasks 300
Completion_time 11520ms
Stage_executed parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53
Job_ID 2
Submission_time 2023-01-12 09:48:46.908000
Run_time 218358ms
Result JobSucceeded
Number_of_stages 1
Stage_ID 3
Number_of_tasks 1135
Number_of_executed_tasks 1135
Completion_time 218299ms
Stage_executed parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53
```

I want the output to be :

```
{
    "Report_for": "Reconciliation",
    "Execution_of": "application_1673496470638_0001",
    "Spark_version": "2.4.7-amzn-0",
    "Java_version": "1.8.0_352 (Amazon.com Inc.)",
    "Start_time": "2023-01-12 09:45:13.360000",
    "Job_ID 0": {
        "Submission_time": "2023-01-12 09:47:20.148000",
        "Run_time": "73957ms",
        "Result": "JobSucceeded",
        "Number_of_stages": "1",
        "Stage_ID 0”: {
            "Number_of_tasks": "16907",
            "Number_of_executed_tasks": "16907",
            "Completion_time": "73207ms",
            "Stage_executed": "parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53"
            "Stage": "parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53",
         },
     },
}
```

I tried defaultdict method but it was generating a json with values as list which was not acceptable to make a table on it. Here's what I did:

```py
import json
from collections import defaultdict

INPUT = 'demofile.txt'
dict1 = defaultdict(list)

def convert():
    with open(INPUT) as f:
        for line in f:
            command, description = line.strip().split(None, 1)
            dict1[command].append(description.strip())
    OUTPUT = open("demo1file.json", "w")
    json.dump(dict1, OUTPUT, indent = 4, sort_keys = False)
```

and was getting this:

```py
     "Report_for": [ "Reconciliation" ], 
     "Execution_of": [ "application_1673496470638_0001" ], 
     "Spark_version": [ "2.4.7-amzn-0" ], 
     "Java_version": [ "1.8.0_352 (Amazon.com Inc.)" ], 
     "Start_time": [ "2023-01-12 09:45:13.360000" ], 
      "Job_ID": [ 
           "0", 
           "1", 
           "2", ....
]]]
```

I just want to convert my text to the above json format so that I can build a table on top of it.

Comment: have you tried reading the file, parsing the lines and building the desired dictionary?

Comment: I was able to read and parse the lines, but was struggling to get the nested structure for job and then stage.

Comment: can you post the code of what you have tried and the results you are getting?

Comment: I tried putting all the duplicate key values all together but it was not supported by athena.

Comment: please edit your question to include the code you have tried and the results you were getting.

Comment: ok, you code is just defining the function `convert` but you are never calling that function. So your code won't actually output anything. Hope that solved your problem, have a nice day.

Comment: I am calling the covert function, and that is working fine. I have added the output after calling the function. But, I am struggling with the idea to make a nested json

Comment: no, you are not, in the code you posted you are not calling the function, and the code you posted should be representative of the problem you are asking. Call the function and that will solve the problem that you have in the code you posted. When you do that, the next question would be: If you don;t want lists why are you initializing your dictionary as `defaultdict(list)`?

Comment: because that was the the only way i was able to get the duplicate values, but i wanted to show a nested structure and have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way, python or one of it's libraries can figure out your nesting requirements, if a flat text is being given as an input. How should it know Stages are inside Jobs...for example.

You will have to programmatically tell your application how it works.

I hacked an example which should work, you can go from there (assuming **input_str** is what you posted as your file content):

```
# define your nesting structure
nesting = {'Job_ID': {'Stage_ID': {}}}
upper_nestings = []
upper_nesting_keys = []

# your resulting dictionary
result_dict = {}

# your "working" dictionaries
current_nesting = nesting
working_dict = result_dict

# parse each line of the input string
for line_str in input_str.split('\n'):

    # key is the first word, value are all consecutive words    
    line = line_str.split(' ')

    # if key is in nesting, create new sub-dict, all consecutive entries are part of the sub-dict        
    if line[0] in current_nesting.keys():
        current_nesting = current_nesting[line[0]]
        upper_nestings.append(line[0])
        upper_nesting_keys.append(line[1])
        working_dict[line_str] = {}
        working_dict = working_dict[line_str]

    else:
        # if a new "parallel" or "upper" nesting is detected, reset your nesting structure
        if line[0] in upper_nestings:
            nests = upper_nestings[:upper_nestings.index(line[0])]
            keys = upper_nesting_keys[:upper_nestings.index(line[0])]
        
            working_dict = result_dict
            for nest in nests:
                working_dict = working_dict[' '.join([nest, keys[nests.index(nest)]])]
    
            upper_nestings = upper_nestings[:upper_nestings.index(line[0])+1]
        
            upper_nesting_keys = upper_nesting_keys[:upper_nestings.index(line[0])]
            upper_nesting_keys.append(line[1])
        
            current_nesting = nesting
            for nest in upper_nestings:
                current_nesting = current_nesting[nest]
        
            working_dict[line_str] = {}
            working_dict = working_dict[line_str]
            continue
        
        working_dict[line[0]] = ' '.join(line[1:])
    
print(result_dict)
```

Results in:

```
{
  'Report_for': 'Reconciliation', 
  'Execution_of': 'application_1673496470638_0001',
  'Spark_version': '2.4.7-amzn-0', 
  'Java_version': '1.8.0_352 (Amazon.com Inc.)', 
  'Start_time': '2023-01-12 09:45:13.360000', 
  'Spark': 'Properties: ', 
  'Job_ID 0': {
    'Submission_time': '2023-01-12 09:47:20.148000', 
    'Run_time': '73957ms', 
    'Result': 'JobSucceeded', 
    'Number_of_stages': '1', 
    'Stage_ID 0': {
      'Number_of_tasks': '16907', 
      'Number_of_executed_tasks': '16907', 
      'Completion_time': '73207ms', 
      'Stage_executed': 'parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53'
    }
  }, 
  'Job_ID 1': {
    'Submission_time': '2023-01-12 09:48:34.177000', 
    'Run_time': '11525ms', 
    'Result': 'JobSucceeded', 
    'Number_of_stages': '2', 
    'Stage_ID 1': {
      'Number_of_tasks': '16907', 
      'Number_of_executed_tasks': '0', 
      'Completion_time': '0ms', 
      'Stage_executed': 'parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53'
    }, 
    'Stage_ID 2': {
      'Number_of_tasks': '300', 
      'Number_of_executed_tasks': '300', 
      'Completion_time': '11520ms', 
      'Stage_executed': 'parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53'
    }
  }, 
  'Job_ID 2': {
    'Submission_time': 
    '2023-01-12 09:48:46.908000', 
    'Run_time': '218358ms', 
    'Result': 'JobSucceeded', 
    'Number_of_stages': '1', 
    'Stage_ID 3': {
      'Number_of_tasks': '1135', 
      'Number_of_executed_tasks': '1135', 
      'Completion_time': '218299ms', 
      'Stage_executed': 'parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53'
    }
  }
}
```

and should pretty much be generically usable for all kinds of nesting definitions from a flat input. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: heyy can you please look into this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75556993/how-to-tranform-my-text-file-into-a-json-file?noredirect=1#comment133305097_75556993