# How to tranform my text file into a json file

Tags: python, json

I have a text file :

```
Report_for Reconciliation
Execution_of application_1673496470638_0001
Spark_version 2.4.7-amzn-0
Java_version 1.8.0_352 (Amazon.com Inc.)
Start_time 2023-01-12 09:45:13.360000
Spark Properties: 
Job_ID 0
Submission_time 2023-01-12 09:47:20.148000
Run_time 73957ms
Result JobSucceeded
Number_of_stages 1
Stage_ID 0
Number_of_tasks 16907
Number_of_executed_tasks 16907
Completion_time 73207ms
Stage_executed parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53
Job_ID 1
Submission_time 2023-01-12 09:48:34.177000
Run_time 11525ms
Result JobSucceeded
Number_of_stages 2
Stage_ID 1
Number_of_tasks 16907
Number_of_executed_tasks 0
Completion_time 0ms
Stage_executed parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53
Stage_ID 2
Number_of_tasks 300
Number_of_executed_tasks 300
Completion_time 11520ms
Stage_executed parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53
Job_ID 2
Submission_time 2023-01-12 09:48:46.908000
Run_time 218358ms
Result JobSucceeded
Number_of_stages 1
Stage_ID 3
Number_of_tasks 1135
Number_of_executed_tasks 1135
Completion_time 218299ms
Stage_executed parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53
```

which I wanted to convert to a json file so that I can build a table on top of that, but my approach is going wrong. Since I am converting it first into a dict with key value pair, I am able to seggregate at Job_ID and Stage_ID, however I want to group all stages under Stages which again comes under Jobs, but was not able to do it.

The json that I am getting:

```
{
  'Report_for': 'Reconciliation', 
  'Execution_of': 'application_1673496470638_0001',
  'Spark_version': '2.4.7-amzn-0', 
  'Java_version': '1.8.0_352 (Amazon.com Inc.)', 
  'Start_time': '2023-01-12 09:45:13.360000', 
  'Spark': 'Properties: ', 
  'Job_ID 0': {
    'Submission_time': '2023-01-12 09:47:20.148000', 
    'Run_time': '73957ms', 
    'Result': 'JobSucceeded', 
    'Number_of_stages': '1', 
    'Stage_ID 0': {
      'Number_of_tasks': '16907', 
      'Number_of_executed_tasks': '16907', 
      'Completion_time': '73207ms', 
      'Stage_executed': 'parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53'
    }
  }, 
  'Job_ID 1': {
    'Submission_time': '2023-01-12 09:48:34.177000', 
    'Run_time': '11525ms', 
    'Result': 'JobSucceeded', 
    'Number_of_stages': '2', 
    'Stage_ID 1': {
      'Number_of_tasks': '16907', 
      'Number_of_executed_tasks': '0', 
      'Completion_time': '0ms', 
      'Stage_executed': 'parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53'
    }, 
    'Stage_ID 2': {
      'Number_of_tasks': '300', 
      'Number_of_executed_tasks': '300', 
      'Completion_time': '11520ms', 
      'Stage_executed': 'parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53'
    }
  }, 
  'Job_ID 2': {
    'Submission_time': 
    '2023-01-12 09:48:46.908000', 
    'Run_time': '218358ms', 
    'Result': 'JobSucceeded', 
    'Number_of_stages': '1', 
    'Stage_ID 3': {
      'Number_of_tasks': '1135', 
      'Number_of_executed_tasks': '1135', 
      'Completion_time': '218299ms', 
      'Stage_executed': 'parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53'
    }
  }
}
```

I want my result to look something like this:

```
{
    'Report_for': 'Reconciliation',
    'Execution_of': 'application_1673496470638_0001',
    'Spark_version': '2.4.7-amzn-0',
    'Java_version': '1.8.0_352 (Amazon.com Inc.)',
    'Start_time': '2023-01-12 09:45:13.360000',
    'Spark': 'Properties: ',
    'Job_ID 0': {
        'Submission_time': '2023-01-12 09:47:20.148000',
        'Run_time': '73957ms',
        'Result': 'JobSucceeded',
        'Number_of_stages': '1',
        'Stage_ID 0': {
            'Number_of_tasks': '16907',
            'Number_of_executed_tasks': '16907',
            'Completion_time': '73207ms',
            'Stage_executed': 'parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53'
        }
    },
    Jobs: {
        {
            'Job_ID': 1 'Submission_time': '2023-01-12 09:48:34.177000',
            'Run_time': '11525ms',
            'Result': 'JobSucceeded',
            'Number_of_stages': '2',
            'Stages: { {
            'Stage_ID': 1,
            'Number_of_tasks': '16907',
            'Number_of_executed_tasks': '0',
            'Completion_time': '0ms',
            'Stage_executed': 'parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53'
        },
        {
            'Stage_ID': 2,
            'Number_of_tasks': '300',
            'Number_of_executed_tasks': '300',
            'Completion_time': '11520ms',
            'Stage_executed': 'parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53'
        }
    },
}, {
    'Job_ID': 2,
    'Submission_time': '2023-01-12 09:48:46.908000',
    'Run_time': '218358ms',
    'Result': 'JobSucceeded',
    'Number_of_stages': '1',
    'Stages': {
        'Stage_ID': 3,
        'Number_of_tasks': '1135',
        'Number_of_executed_tasks': '1135',
        'Completion_time': '218299ms',
        'Stage_executed': 'parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53'
    }
}
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: No easy way other than going line by line, splitting on the first space for key-value and if statements for when to start and end a level of nesting. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you want a stable solution for such nested data structures, you'll need to build a little parser here. You might want take a look at [ply](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/).

Comment: I have tried first coverting into a dict differentiating on the basis of key-value pair which are separated by a space, and then clubbing all the info under the job and stages

Comment: I'm not very familiar working with python, hence facing a little problem, can someone help me here